# Suddenly getting "No more authentication methods available" from eclipse egit from formerly working installation

Tags: eclipse, git

I've had Eclipse installed for quite a while. I upgraded to 2018-12 a few weeks ago. I've had ssh authentication set up for all my git repos (centrally stored in BitBucket Server) for a long time. It's been working perfectly fine.

Today I had to reboot my Windows7 laptop for some automated installations, which happens a few times a month.

I restarted Eclipse and suddenly I'm finding that all of my git repos are failing authentication. I'm seeing this in the log:

```
!MESSAGE ssh://git@.../....git: No more authentication methods available
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@.../.....git: No more authentication methods available
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PullOperation$PullJob.run(PullOperation.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@.../.....git: No more authentication methods available
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSessionFactory.getSession(SshdSessionFactory.java:249)
```

I then went to one of my local repositories in my Cygwin shell and tried a "git pull". This worked perfectly fine.

The only recent change I made that might be related to this is that I installed the Windows version of git, in addition to the Cygwin git. I put it at the end of the PATH. I don't see how that could be affecting this, as Eclipse is using jgit.

**Update**:

I think I just solved the problem, but I'm not sure what the real problem was.

When I installed 2018-12 a few weeks ago, I thought I noticed a mention of upcoming changes to what the default ssh client would be.  I noticed that I was currently set to use JSch, and I thought the release notes said that it would be moving to "Apache MINA", so I decided to change it now and see how it worked.  This was working fine for a couple of weeks.

Just now I tried changing that field back to "JSch" and then doing a pull.  It worked fine.  Just to be sure, I changed it back to "Apache MINA" and tried it again.  Still failed.  Changed it back to "JSch" and it's working.

I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Would Cygwin and Windows git both read ssh keys from the same location? Are the egit preferences still pointing to the right key file(s)?

Comment: Is there something in the error log? Please report it to Eclipse so it can be fixed before _Apache MINA_ becomes the default.

Comment: You mean besides the trace I already included from the log, and said it was from the log?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean is there anything else in the log file regarding Git and is this the full stack trace?

Comment: to whoever is coming here : this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/56223580/5123867

Answer (score 5):

This is happened to me today... I don't have any clue why it's happening.. I tried removing eclipse and installed again... same problem again... I checked all the settings and everything seemed fine... the error message was not something to guess easily...

What i have done

- My ssh keys are not the default one... I have a folders called `github`, `internal` and `deployed` inside `~/.ssh`
- So, In eclipse I went to `Window > Prefrences -> Network -> SSH2` in private keys I have given the path to my keys... but i didn't change `SSH2 home` directory... this is the culprit.. I will tell you later why

  - `SSH2 Home directory = ~/.ssh`
  - `path to private key = ~/.ssh/github/slokesh`
- I changed ssh client in `Preferences -> Team -> git` but every single time the same error was showing up...

So, then I went back to step 2, then there I changed `SSH2 home` directory to `~/.ssh/github` and the `path to private key` to `slokesh` then it worked...

I hope this helps... if anything is unclear please leave a comment...

I feel that the error message they are throwing could be more verbose and clear. Also, there should be a note in the `SSH2 home and private key path` fields because the private key path they are taking as relative to `SSH2 home`. But unfortunately they are not giving...

Comment: @Bhargav Rao : I have deleted the other post and keeping this one because this answer suits for this question than the other